# React Admin - How To Hide Actions Buttons

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

How could I hide the action buttons in the React-Admin `2.2.0` framework?

For example, I want to hide just the export button, or show only the Refresh and Export buttons.

Answer (score 21):

Well, I found the solution myself.

When you want to hide all buttons:

```
import { List, CardActions } from 'react-admin';

const NoneActions = props => (
    <CardActions />
);

export const AdminList = (props) => (
    <List title="Admin List" {...props} actions={<NoneActions />}>
        ...
    </List>
);
```

When you want to show only the reload Button:

```
import { List, CardActions, RefreshButton } from 'react-admin';

const ActionsRefresh = props => (
    <CardActions>
        <RefreshButton />
    </CardActions>
);

export const AdminList = (props) => (
    <List title="Admin List" {...props} actions={<ActionsRefresh />}>
        ...
    </List>
);
```

Comment: This is a very correct and readable solution! You can mark it as solved.
It will help further readers +1

Comment: Wish I could more upvote this - The docs are pretty convoluted and force more complexity in their description without providing simple context.

Answer (score 0):

```
<List actions={null} {...props}>
```